# The properties of $A^{1 /2} B^{1 / 2 } - B^{1 / 2} A^{1 / 2}$.

Tags: probability, matrices, asymptotics, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Suppose $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ is a strictly positive defined symmetric matrix. Now suppose there exists a weakly consistent estimator for the matrix $A$, say $B_n$, which satisfies $\| B_n - A\|_{\infty} \rightarrow_p 0$.

Does any know the properties of
$$A^{1 /2} B_n^{1 / 2 } - B_n^{1 / 2} A^{1 / 2}.$$
Thanks so much!

PS: the property I would like to obtain is something like
$$\frac{\|A^{1 /2} B_n^{1 / 2 } - B_n^{1 / 2} A^{1 / 2}\|}{\|A - B_n\|} \, \rightarrow_p 0$$
under some proper norm $\|\cdot\|$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Does this possible?

Comment: what does $o(*)$ mean?

Comment: @Schach21 Sorry, I should clarify it. $o(*)$ represents the small order, that is under some proper norm. For $B = B_n$, do we have $\frac{\| A^{1/2} B^{1/2} - B^{1 /2} A^{1/2}\|} 
{\| A - B\| }\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: why is there an $n$? in the problem formulation there's no $n$. And if $B=B_n$, then why is there need for an $n$?

Comment: @Schach21 I did not state my question clearly... I have updated it. Thanks!

Comment: what does weakly consistent estimator exactly mean here? $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}||A-B_n||=0$?

Comment: @Schach21 $ \| A - B_n\|_{\infty} \rightarrow_p 0$

Comment: $B^{1/2}$ is well-defined only when $B$ is positive self-adjoint. Is it?

Comment: @Chrystomath Yeah. I think $B_n \rightarrow_p A$, and $A^{1/2}$ is well-defined, so $B_n^{1/2}$ is also well-defined with probability one when $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C:=A^{1/2}$ and $D:=B^{1/2}$. Then it is not necessarily the case that $$\frac{\|CD-DC\|}{\|C^2-D^2\|}\to0$$ as $D\to C$.

Here is a counterexample. Let $C:=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, $D:=\begin{pmatrix}2&\epsilon\\\epsilon&1\end{pmatrix}$, with $\epsilon\to0$, and $A=C^2$, $B=D^2$. Then $$\|CD-DC\|_F=\left\|\begin{pmatrix}0&\epsilon\\-\epsilon&0\end{pmatrix}\right\|_F=\sqrt2|\epsilon|$$
$$\|A-B\|_F=\|C^2-D^2\|_F=\left\|\begin{pmatrix}\epsilon^2 & 3 \epsilon \\
 3 \epsilon &\epsilon^2\end{pmatrix}\right\|_F=\sqrt2|\epsilon|\sqrt{9+\epsilon^2}$$ Hence the ratio $\frac{\|CD-DC\|_F}{\|A-B\|_F}\to\frac{1}{3}$ as $\epsilon\to0$.

N.B. All norms on matrices are equivalent, so it does not matter what specific norm one picks.

Comment: Thanks so much!